# How do I mock JoinRow for unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, jdbi

I have looked at code base of jdbi v3 but still can't figure out a way to mock `Stream<JoinRow>` returned by Dao class.

Constructor is package protected which is only invoked from `JoinRowMapper`'s specialize function which itself needs `StatementContext`.

Is there any way to mock `JoinRow` object for unit testing purposes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @qualidafial Any inputs

Comment: @brianm can you help

Comment: It's not clear why do you need to mock ```Stream<JoinRow>```. Add the intention and examples, because it seems like an instance of [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 0):

Not clear, why you need to mock `Stream<JoinRow>`. But if you can't mock it, you can spy it :) Just, use [Mockito Spy](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.24.0/org/mockito/Spy.html), or [Spring @SpyBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/SpyBean.html) depending on your context.

However, Jdbi has pretty good support for [testing](http://jdbi.org/#_testing) without mocking anything - just by using embedded DB (like H2) and [JdbiRule](http://jdbi.org/apidocs/org/jdbi/v3/testing/JdbiRule.html).

Also, there are good examples of [Jdbi tests](https://github.com/jdbi/jdbi/tree/f3173087f9fbfd3a9c722fe9218fafbea506decd/sqlobject/src/test/java/org/jdbi/v3/sqlobject) in their Git repo. Specifically for [Stream](https://github.com/jdbi/jdbi/blob/f3173087f9fbfd3a9c722fe9218fafbea506decd/sqlobject/src/test/java/org/jdbi/v3/sqlobject/TestStream.java).

Hopefully, this answer clarifies something.